# two or more SDP610 Pressure sensor Interface with Arduino uno using I2C

Tags: arduino, sensor, i2c, pressure

I have interfaced one SDP610 Pressure Sensor using I2C with Arduino Uno R3.
Now I want to Interface more than one sensor with same controller(uno board).
I don't find any higher or lower address in my sensor datasheet.  In my code address of sensor is

```
typedef enum { eSDP6xAddress = 0x40, //(64) } PRES_SENSOR_P;
```

> The I2C address consists of a 7-digit binary value. By default, the I2C address is set to 64 (binary: 1000 000).The address is always followed by a write bit (0) or read bit (1). The default hexadecimal I2C header for readaccess to the sensor is therefore h81.
>
> from section 3.2 in the [SDP610 datasheet](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/8_Differential_Pressure/Sensirion_Differential_Pressure_Sensors_SDP600Series_Datasheet_V.1.9.pdf)

Is there any chances to change the address of SDP610 sensor and its possible to interface with same I2C bus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the I<sup>2</sup>C slave address in this sensor.  It's hard-wired inside.

If you want to have several of these sensors, you have these options:

1. Create a separate I<sup>2</sup>C buses.  One of them can be bit-banged.
   [Having said that, I don't know how well the Arduino libraries can support this.]
2. Multiplex the I<sup>2</sup>C bus.  If you connect one SDP610 at a time, there will be no address collision.
3. Use an [I<sup>2</sup>C address translator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/214906/7036).

**Related threads**
[i2C multiplexer to use multiple sensor of the same type](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132498/i2c-multiplexer-to-use-multiple-sensor-of-the-same-type)
[How to connect multiple of the same device to an Arduino using I2C?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130235/how-to-connect-multiple-of-the-same-device-to-an-arduino-using-i2c)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/323893/68606

Comment: Thanks to Nick and whisk.i will go ahead with I2C multiplexer.

Answer (score 1):

According to this question on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, the SDP610 can have its I²C address reprogrammed, but the manufacturer does not release those details publically, due to the possibility of destroying the device if this is done incorrectly:

[Multiple differential air pressure sensors using I²C bus?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37455/multiple-differential-air-pressure-sensors-using-i%C2%B2c-bus)

If you don't want to (or cannot) follow that process, then there are several previous questions here which explain the use of I²C multiplexors, switches, and address translators - all of which can allow you to use multiple sensors with the same I²C address, with varying degrees of effort and cost e.g.:

[How to resolve I2C address clashes?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/how-to-resolve-i2c-address-clashes)

[How to connect multiple of the same device to an Arduino using I2C?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130235/how-to-connect-multiple-of-the-same-device-to-an-arduino-using-i2c)